# Setting element unique in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XSD which I need to add another unique constraint to.

I'd like to make Name unique within its parent Groups element, however a group can be repeated in each WikiMeta.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="AllMeta">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WikiMeta">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Subject" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="PageTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="PageMetaDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xs:element name="Articles">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="WikiArticle" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="FileName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                      <xs:unique name="uniqueFileName">
                        <xs:selector xpath="WikiMeta"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="FileName"/>
                      </xs:unique>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Groups">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WikiGroup">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="subject">
      <xs:selector xpath="WikiMeta"/>
      <xs:field xpath="Subject"/>
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="fileName">
      <xs:selector xpath="WikiMeta/Articles/WikiArticle"/>
      <xs:field xpath="FileName"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the constraint to the element which defined the level of visibility. Here is the modified XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="AllMeta">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WikiMeta">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Subject" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="PageTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="PageMetaDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="Articles">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="WikiArticle" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="FileName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:unique name="uniqueFileName">
                                                <xs:selector xpath="WikiMeta"/>
                                                <xs:field xpath="FileName"/>
                                            </xs:unique>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="Groups">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WikiGroup">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                                <xs:key name="groupkey">
                                    <xs:selector xpath="WikiGroup"/>
                                    <xs:field xpath="Name"/>
                                </xs:key>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="subject">
            <xs:selector xpath="WikiMeta"/>
            <xs:field xpath="Subject"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="fileName">
            <xs:selector xpath="WikiMeta/Articles/WikiArticle"/>
            <xs:field xpath="FileName"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Visually might be easier to understand:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I'm new to xml/xsd design, it's pretty difficult getting examples that relate to your exact needs so thank you for your clear example. Out of interest what do you use for your XSD visual editor ?